# Transitioning to state with query parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [Angular UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage my client side routing.  I'm trying to use the [`$state.go()`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) method to switch states, but I want to include a query parameter in the new URL, and I'm not sure how to.  I've already defined my target state in my app module:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login?returnurl',
    //more properties
}
```

And I want to navigate to `http://localhost:3000/login?returnurl=%2fhome`.

How would I format my `$state.go()` call correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$state.go('login', { 'returnurl': '/home' });
```

or if you probably want to call the login page from a http response interceptor on a 401:

```
$state.go('login', { 'returnurl': $state.current.url });
```